How to keep the lines of Popen.communicate together?
I want to write the STDOUT of a subprocess.Popen.communicate to a pd.DataFrame. I took some SO threads and combined them to this code:
import subprocess
import io
import pandas as pd


strings = ['Hello\tWorld!', 'This\tis', 'a\tTest!']

string = '\n'.join(strings)

cmd_grep = ['grep', 's']

process_grep = subprocess.Popen(cmd_grep, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
grep_stdout = process_grep.communicate(input=string.encode('utf-8'))[0].decode('utf-8')
grep_csv = io.StringIO()

for line in grep_stdout:
    grep_csv.write(line)

grep_csv.seek(0)
grep_results = pd.read_csv(grep_csv,
                           sep='\t',
                           header=None,
                           names=['Word1', 'Word2'])
grep_csv.close()

grep_results

This works for easy outputs. But if I want to filter the lines, like this
    if line.startswith('This'):
        grep_csv.write(line)

it doesn't work anymore. This is because my for line in grep_stdout: does not iterate lines but characters (you can see this by adding a print(line). Any idea, how I can keep the lines together?

Use for line in grep_stdout.splitlines(): to process it as lines.

Guess I need to change grep_csv.write(line) to grep_csv.write(line + '\n') then, wouldn't I (I was on a similar path)?

This is a strange use of grep. Is it used simply as an example of something that you can call and returns data, or are you really using grep to suppress the first line? I'm only asking to see if .communicate is even needed for you.

No, it's just an example. The actual command give a much bigger output :). I used it, because I needed sth. that takes STDIN and that was the first I could think of, because initially, I piped an echo command, but I ran into issues, because the args where too long in some cases.

Yes, or you can use grep_stdout.splitlines(keeplinebreaks=True)

communicate keeps the writing of stdin plus the reading of stdout and stderr from deadlocking at the cost of bringing in the entire output streams as bytes objects. You can do the same thing as communicate with your own threads to tweak the algorithm.
In your case, you aren't redirecting stderr and you'd like to read stdout line by line if possible. Since this is a UTF8 encoding where newline is still just a single character, you can use the reader that is already on stdout to do the job. Delegate writing to a background thread and use the main thread for stdout.
import subprocess
import io
import pandas as pd
import threading

def stream_writer(data, stream):
    """write and close a stream"""
    try:
        while data:
            count = stream.write(data)
            data = data[count:]
    finally:
        stream.close()

strings = ['Hello\tWorld!', 'This\tis', 'a\tTest!']

string = '\n'.join(strings)

cmd_grep = ['grep', 's']

process_grep = subprocess.Popen(cmd_grep, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
       stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
writer = threading.Thread(target=stream_writer, args=(string.encode('utf-8'),
        process_grep.stdin))
writer.start()

# read and filter result then create dataframe
with io.StringIO() as grep_csv:
    for bline in process_grep.stdout:
        line = bline.decode("utf-8")
        if not line.startswith('This'):
            grep_csv.write(line)
    grep_csv.seek(0)

    writer.join()
    process_grep.wait()

    grep_results = pd.read_csv(grep_csv,
                           sep='\t',
                           header=None,
                           names=['Word1', 'Word2'])

print(grep_results)

